# How to save a bitmap as an png in console application of c#

Tags: c#, bitmap, png, console-application

I am doing a console application in c#. In this app, I have to create a bitmap of png type and it has to to be stored in some defined path (say C: or D: drive).

In a windows application I have the below code to create a bitmap and it will be shown in a picture box.

```
void CreateBitmap()
{
    System.Drawing.Bitmap flag = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(10, 10);
    for( int x = 0; x < flag.Height; ++x )
      for( int y = 0; y < flag.Width; ++y )
        flag.SetPixel(x, y, Color.White);
      for( int x = 0; x < flag.Height; ++x )
        flag.SetPixel(x, x, Color.Red);
    pictureBox1.Image = flag;
}
```

How can I create and store this in a specified path using a console application?

I have changed my code as below but still error exists:

```
static void CreatePng(string[] binvalues)
{
    String aName = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
    String aPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(aName);
    string[] ExecDirectories = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(aPath);

    System.Drawing.Bitmap flag = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(10, 10);

    for (int x = 0; x < flag.Height; ++x)
        for (int y = 0; y < flag.Width; ++y)
            flag.SetPixel(x, y, Color.White);
    for (int x = 0; x < flag.Height; ++x)
        flag.SetPixel(x, x, Color.Red);
    flag.Save(aPath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
}
```

It is showing run-time error in last line where flag.save seems something wrong?

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/

Comment: @Marteen: You could at least make the effort to package that link into a nice comment...while I agree with the link and it's purpose, your comment sucks and [is not really helpful](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147161/since-when-is-http-whathaveyoutried-com-banned).

Answer (score 1):

Use the same code, and instead of assigning to a `PictureBox`, call the `Save()` method on the bitmap:

```
flag.Save("yourpath", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

Note that you may have to add a reference to `System.Drawing` in your console application, as it is not there by default.

Answer (score 0):

Now, I've never done this myself using C# so someone more inclined could possibly help but here's what I was able to find out.

1) You need to have your image data stored in a `Bitmap`. From the looks of things you're doing this already with `flag`

2) You need to call the `save()` function on the `Bitmap`:

```
flag.Save(filename, ImageFormat.Png);
```

3) `filename` would be a `String` that you define. This is fairly easy as you could simply have the application prompt the user to enter a path and save it.

Questions?

Disclaimer: I received my info from [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2205742/c-sharp-bitmap-save-transparancy-doesnt-save-in-png). There is a lot of discussion on the "proper" way to save a png you can dig from.

Comment: Can you post the runtime error for us? There should be a stack trace detailing exactly what's wrong.... might be missing directory, bad format, or file not found? Something else?

Comment: The Error thrown is  :  " An unhandled Exception of type 'System.Runtime.Interopservices.ExternalException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll"                                                    An Additional information : A generic error occurred in GDI+

Comment: Are you saving it to a new file or overwriting an old one? You'd get an exception like that if you were trying to save over a file that is in use. EDIT: Its also possible that the path you're saving to doesn't exist. Are you checking to make sure the path is valid?

Comment: the filename is not used while running., its a new onebut donno., still throws an error

Comment: Looking at your code again, you're saving to `aPath` but no file name? try `flag.Save(aPath + "image.png", ImageFormat.Png);` and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
flag.Save(filename, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

1. You don't need to add the image to a `PictureBox`. You have a console application and `PictureBox` is a visual control.
2. For future questions it would be nice if you spent a minimum amount of time of searching SO or other sources for an answer first
3. The question is not tagged correctly. If you want to save  a `System.Drawing.Bitmap` it can not be tagged `BitmapImage` as this is for WPF only. I changed this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code-:

```
public bool ResizeImage(string OriginalFilepath, string NewFilepath)
{
  Bitmap original = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(OriginalFilepath);
  Bitmap resized = new Bitmap(original, new Size(Width,Height));
  resized.Save(NewFilepath.png);      
}
```