# Create a PNG from an array of bytes

Tags: c#, .net, png

I have a 1 dimensional array of bytes, with separate values for A, R, G, and B, and I know the height and width of the expected image. How can I encode this data and save it as a PNG?

Comment: Who is downvoting this question, and why?

Comment: See edit to my answer. Perhaps you can use the array directly using WPF.

Comment: ?. Because there is a straightforward solution, possibly. Other than in your comments on answers to this quite broad question, you don't mention anything on efficiency or whatever is stopping you from using any native PNG support in .NET, or even libpng.

Comment: @Jongware: Then you should be constructive and add a comment to this question! There are about 7 downvotes and for now only on comment saying why. For me this is a short and clear question. I don't want to read so much unnecessary text.

Comment: I wasn't aware of any native PNG support options. If I knew of such options to use and could use them, I wouldn't have asked the question. If I had more information to give, I would have given it.

Comment: @Jongware if there was a straightforward solution to a straightforward question, then please provide the answer. Judging by the variety of answers below, there may not be one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
byte[] data = new byte[] {
    255, 255, 000, 000,  255, 255, 255, 255,  255, 255, 255, 255,  255, 255, 255, 255,  255, 255, 000, 000, 
    255, 255, 255, 255,  255, 255, 000, 000,  255, 255, 255, 255,  255, 255, 000, 000,  255, 255, 255, 255, 
    255, 255, 255, 255,  255, 255, 255, 255,  255, 255, 000, 000,  255, 255, 255, 255,  255, 255, 255, 255, 
    255, 255, 255, 255,  255, 255, 000, 000,  255, 255, 255, 255,  255, 255, 000, 000,  255, 255, 255, 255, 
    255, 255, 000, 000,  255, 255, 255, 255,  255, 255, 255, 255,  255, 255, 255, 255,  255, 255, 000, 000 
  };

  Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(5, 5);
  for (int y = 0; y < 5; ++y)
    for (int x = 0; x < 5; ++x)
    {
      int offset = y * 5 * 4 + x * 4;
      bmp.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(data[offset], data[offset + 1], data[offset + 2], data[offset + 3]));
    }
  bmp.Save(@"c:\tmp.png");
}
```

---

If the values in your array are ordered this way: B G R A B G R A B G R A ... you could use the following code, which should be faster:

```
byte[] data = new byte[] {
  // B    G    R    A     B    G    R    A     B    G    R    A
      0,   0, 255, 255,    0,   0,   0, 255,    0, 255,   0, 255,
      0,   0,   0, 255,    0, 255,   0, 255,  255, 255, 255, 255,
      0, 255,   0, 255,    0,   0,   0, 255,  255,   0,   0, 255
  };
  int width = 3;
  int height = 3;

  Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
  var bitmapData = bmp.LockBits(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, bmp.PixelFormat);
  Marshal.Copy(data, 0, bitmapData.Scan0, data.Length);
  bmp.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
  bmp.Save(@"c:\tmp.png");
```

This image should look like this: [image]

Comment: This is a pretty good solution. I was hoping for something more efficient than setting individual pixels.

Comment: @Stealth Rabbi: I added an alternative

Comment: Does this require running in an unsafe block?

Comment: No, you just have to add 
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

Comment: OK, the second solution basically works. I realized thought that my byte array is R,G,B,A, so the colors are off (what I specified in the question is wrong). Having RGBA is not a supported pixel format, so I guess I have to adjust my code that generates the byte array to put Alpha first.

Comment: What do you mean with 'off'? I added a 3x3 image as byte array and also the PNG that is created by the code.

Comment: Sorry. I mean that R, G, B, A values were swapped, and the image did not appear to be the right colors. I then went back and read your note above the second example about having to be in the B, G, R, A order. It now shows up just fine. Sorry, a confusing comment.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a Bitmap and [Bitmap.SetPixel()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.setpixel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Then [save the Bitmap as png](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9t4syfhh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) using `ImageFormat.Png` . Also, you might have to make sure that [the Bitmap format maintains transparency](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7666180/939213) .

(See the other answer here for a faster way than SetPixel.)

EDIT

Perhaps [WPF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa346816%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) can use the array directly. (I don't have much experience with it.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a faster solution using `Unsafe pointers` and `LockBits`

```
    public unsafe Bitmap Retreive(byte[] values)
    {
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(Width, Height); //enter your width and height here.
        BitmapData bmData = bmp.LockBits(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bmp.PixelFormat);
        IntPtr scan0 = bmData.Scan0;
        int stride = bmData.Stride;
        int nWidth = bmp.Width;
        int nHeight = bmp.Height;

        for (int y = 0; y < nHeight; y++)
        {
            //define the pointers inside the first loop for parallelizing
            byte* p = (byte*)scan0.ToPointer();
            p += y * stride;

            for (int x = 0; x < nWidth; x++)
            {
                //fill as  the values stored in you byte array;
                p[0] = values[0];// R component.
                p[1] = values[1];// G component.
                p[2] = values[2];// B component.
                p[3] = values[3];// Alpha component.
                p += 4;
            }
        }

        bmp.UnlockBits(bmData);
        return bmp;
    }
```

Just fill the `p[]` values like they stored in your array.

Goodluck.

Comment: I haven't run unsafe code before. What are the impacts of doing this?

Comment: @StealthRabbi it's not dangerous haha :) it's just acessing the pixels throught pointers which cause the entire process to run significantly faster.  you can read more about it here  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288474(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: @Slashy: Why is it called "unsafe" if it is not dangerous?

Comment: @user1027167 i dont know the real reason but actually it's because it used unmanaged pointers... you can try my method yourself.. you could see it's running x100 faster :)

Comment: @Slashy: I just wanted to point out, that it is dangerous to use unsafe code ;) You should be very careful with that...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest it is better to look for a platform-independent solution that doesn't depend on building a desktop image or a Bitmap (neither GDI+ Bitmap nor WPF WriteableBitmap).  BigGustave (available on NuGet) did the trick for me.   https://github.com/EliotJones/BigGustave It creates the PNGs directly.