# Array to image alternatives

Tags: c++, arrays, image, png, ppm

For a project, I'm using the MLX90461 IR camera.
And I'm using some C++ code to read the data of the camera.

The data of this camera is stored in an array of 192 elements (16x12 RES).
In this array, I store the measured temperature for that pixel.

Next, I convert that temperature to RGB values and store those as well.
Because I need 3 values per pixel the array has 576 elements. (192 * 3).

So now I have an array filled with data. And I want to make an image of all this data.

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36374100/10352461) example and it works great.

Now comes the but... But:

1. It outputs a `.ppm` file
2. The output is just 16x12 pixels

And I want to use the output as a sort of live stream, so the `.ppm` file type is not really great.

So My questions are.

1. Is this way of doing things in the right direction?
2. Is there a way to output a more "common" file type like a `.png`
3. Is C++ the best way to do this type of data processing
   I was thinking to use Python to make an image based on the array.

The end result I'm liking to have is something like this: [visualization on display](https://wiki.seeedstudio.com/Grove-Thermal-Imaging-Camera-IR-Array/#outcome-of-visualization-on-wio-terminal) (see GIF below code)

```cpp
void print_pixels(){
    static uint8_t pixels[576];
    uint16_t l = 0;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 12 ; i++){ //rows
        for(int j = 0 ; j < 16 ; j++){ // cols
            struct CRGB color = tempToColor(temperatures[j+16*i]);
            pixels[l] = color.r;
            l++;
            pixels[l] = color.g;
            l++;
            pixels[l] = color.b;
            l++;
            printf("T%4.2f,R%i,G%i,B%i : ", temperatures[j+16*i], pixels[l - 3], pixels[l - 2], pixels[l - 1]);
        }
        std::cout << "\n\n";
    }

    FILE *imageFile;
    int height=12,width=16;

    imageFile=fopen("/home/pi/output_IR_camera.ppm","wb");
    if(imageFile==NULL){
        perror("ERROR: Cannot open output file");
        exit(1);
    }
    fprintf(imageFile,"P6\n");               // P6 filetype
    fprintf(imageFile,"%d %d\n",width,height);   // dimensions
    fprintf(imageFile,"255\n");              // Max pixel

    fwrite(pixels,1,576,imageFile);
    fclose(imageFile);

}

struct CRGB tempToColor(float temp) {
    struct CRGB color;
    if (temp > MAX_TEMP) {
        color.r = 255;
        color.g = 0;
        color.b = 255;
    } else if (temp >= MIN_TEMP + PEAK_STEPS * 4) {
        color.r = round(255 * (temp - (MIN_TEMP + PEAK_STEPS * 4.0)) / PEAK_STEPS);
        color.g = 0;
        color.b = 255;
    } else if (temp >= MIN_TEMP + PEAK_STEPS * 3) {
        color.r = 0;
        color.g = round(255 * (6 - (temp - (MIN_TEMP + PEAK_STEPS * 3.0)) / PEAK_STEPS));
        color.b = 255;
    } else if (temp >= MIN_TEMP + PEAK_STEPS * 2) {
        color.r = 0;
        color.g = 255;
        color.b = round(255 * (temp - (MIN_TEMP + PEAK_STEPS * 2.0)) / PEAK_STEPS);
    } else if (temp >= MIN_TEMP + PEAK_STEPS * 1) {
        color.r = round(255 * (6 - (temp - (MIN_TEMP + PEAK_STEPS * 1.0)) / PEAK_STEPS));
        color.g = 255;
        color.b = 0;
    } else if (temp >= MIN_TEMP) {
        color.r = 255;
        color.g = round(255 * ((temp - MIN_TEMP) / PEAK_STEPS));
        color.b = 0;
    } else {
        color.r = 255;
        color.g = 0;
        color.b = 0;
    }
    return color;
}
```

Comment: OpenCV has some nifty functions like `cv::imwrite` that can be used. Often times, you will find people manipulating visual data (e.g., camera-source or otherwise) using a `cv::Mat` and OpenCV library functions to manipulate said `Mat`. Hope this helps

Comment: @dddJewelsbbb
 I wanted to stay away from OpenCV, because, well it's not really a lightweight library.

Comment: @dddJewelsbbb

something like this: https://thecodinginterface.com/blog/opencv-Mat-from-array-and-vector/
What is the output file than?

Comment: Sort of, that just displays to a screen. The [OpenCV docs](https://docs.opencv.org/master/db/deb/tutorial_display_image.html) have an example of writing to a file. OpenCV is very frequently used when manipulating, moving or otherwise processing image data. I am sure there are other options out there for you. If you feel like writing out a PNG, and don't want the overhead of OpenCV, you can probably look into [libpng](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html).

Comment: What output do you actually want? A web-page? An X11 window? What OS are you using? Do you want the output on a different PC? Multiple PCs? How about throwing the image into **Redis** then you can pick it up from any machine and display it using any language - completely independently.

Comment: well, the output is not really important to me. I have a simple webserver running on the pi and I wanted to show the IR image on there. But I think a .ppm file is not really the best chose for a website. Something like a .png would work better.
Also, the output is maxed 2 pc / phones in this case.

Comment: You can easily resize a PPM file and convert to PNG with **ImageMagick** like this `convert input.ppm -resize 160x120 output.png` or with **NetPBM** which is smaller and lighter weight, or with **PIL/Pillow** if you like **Python**.